# Find duplicate records in table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following:

```
| ID | Short Name | Long Name |
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | s1         | l2        |
| 2  | s1         | l2        |
| 3  | s1         | l2        |
| 4  | s5         | l6        |
| .. | ...        |           |
```

I want to get all records that share the same Short Name and Long Name. I need their shared short name, long name, and 3 duplicates' IDs. For this particular example, I want {s1, l2, 1,2,3}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly simple problem to solve. Basically what you want to do is write a subquery that counts the number of rows that match on your specified field for each row in your query. I have included a few examples below.

**Find all rows that are duplicates and match on both name fields**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName AS T2 WHERE T2.ShortName = TableName.ShortName AND T2.LongName = TableName.LongName) > 1;
```

**Find all rows that are duplicates and match on the short name**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName AS T2 WHERE T2.ShortName = TableName.ShortName) > 1;
```

**Find all rows that are duplicates and match on the long name**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName AS T2 WHERE T2.LongName = TableName.LongName) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a a self join of your table and select those rows where the two names are equal and the `id`s differ:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM <table> t1, <table> t2
 WHERE t1.id        <> t2.id
   AND t1.short_name = t2.short_name
   AND t1.long_name  = t2.long_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exits` to see if there are any other data exists with the same condition where ID is not same.

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 
where exists (
  select 1 from table_name t2 
  where 
  t1.ID <> t2.ID 
  and t1.`Short Name` = t2.`Short Name` 
  and t1.`Long Name` = t2.`Long Name`
);
```